# Como generar degradado de color en Sound Bars with Reflection js/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]
Como generar degradado como la imagen que adjunto en una onda de sonido

```js
var elem = $('div');
var count = elem.length;

var loop = function(){ 
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var height = (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
      $this.css({
        'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0,'+(.75-($this.index()/count)/2)+')',
        'bottom': height,
        'height': height
      });
    });
    loop();
  }, 300);
  
}
    
loop();
```

```css
body {
 padding: 100px 0 0 100px; 
}

div {
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 2px;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.35, transparent), to(white));
}


/*estilos que probe yo pero no me funciono*/
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 3px;
  z-index: 20;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#febf0d), color-stop(0.35, #febf0d), to(#febf0d));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con la funcion de `liner-gradient` en la propiedad `background` del `.css()` lo puedes lograr, solo le indicamos que tendra la direccion del degradado hacia abajo para que se visualice el primer color desde abajo, el cual es el verde, si quieres invertir los colores solo lo cambias a `to top`, y luego se colocan los colores con los que quieres realizar el degradado, el cual el primero es el rgba del verde y el segundo es amarillo aunque tambien lo puedes remplazar por el rgba que desees.

```js
var elem = $('div');
var count = elem.length;

var loop = function(){ 
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var height = (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
      $this.css({
        'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(61, 175, 5,'+(.75-($this.index()/count)/2)+'),yellow)',
        'bottom': height,
        'height': height
      });
    });
    
    loop();
  }, 300);
  
}
    
loop();
```

```css
body {
 padding: 100px 0 0 100px; 
}

div {
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 2px;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.35, transparent), to(white));
}


/*estilos que probe yo pero no me funciono*/
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 3px;
  z-index: 20;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#febf0d), color-stop(0.35, #febf0d), to(#febf0d));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Gracias Santiago era lo que quería. gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @ElectricMarian Me alegra poder haberte ayudado, que te termine de ir muy bien!

Comment: Muchas gracias! saludos!